# Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Eclipse Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Eclipse

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, performance-testing, gatling

I am running gateling project on gradle.
Using **Java 1.11**, (openjdk)
Gradle **6.8**,
Scala **2.12.8**,

buidl.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "3.3.4"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Project structure :

[image: 1]

While running with ./gradlew clean build gatlingRun-$1 getting below error

Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.14.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe''

**Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Eclipse
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Eclipse**

any help please. thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems execution command doesn't escape path properly, so "Files\Eclipse" is treated as a separate parameter

Comment: thanks a lot, I changed the java installation path its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has been deprecated for quite some time and replaced with the official gatling-gradle plugin, see  https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/